# Tool to remove system bars (status bar + bottom bar) from Android screenshots

Tags: android, linux, image-processing, screenshot

I have hundreds of Android screenshots, and must remove the system bars (status bar + bottom bar) from them, because they add no value and take precious marketing/documentation space.

- The screenshots are taken on various Android variants, so the size/color/shapes of the bars may vary. I expect the tool to recognize the bars of the most popular Android variants and adapt.
- None of the screenshots are full-screen, so they all have these bars.
- Free, runnable on Linux desktop (Mac/Windows/Android acceptable too).
- Ideally command-line, or at least able to process all files in a folder without repeating steps for each file.
- I know that the bars *may* have some information (notifications, available buttons, etc) but in my case I consider that this information does not justify the space taken.

Example:

[image] becomes [image]

Comment: If the sizes of the bars would be all the same, ImageMagick would be the perfect candidate for that. So in case you cannot find a perfect solution: if picking the sizes from the "largest example" and cutting the same area off from all wouldn't cut off too much in your opinion, that might be an easy approach.

Comment: In your example, the image has been upscaled back to the original height after the bars are removed. Edit your question to clarify whether you want the program to do this, too.

Comment: @Izzy: What are the most extreme Android versions you know (with the smallest/biggest bars)? I guess the amount to crop also depends on screen resolution?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul Oh, on a lot of things I can think of: Android version, ROM variant, manufacturers' "special adaptions" … So it's hard to give a number here. If you don't need it too accurate, randomly pick one with a big bar and add some pixels to be on the safe side (say 10% of the bar's height). My guess is variations mostly apply to the navigation bar (bottom), while the notification bar height (top) will be more or less constant (unless you've got tablet screenshots in that collection as well).